# Facing some errors in CRUD operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, crud

I created a program for CRUD but facing issues
Controller program :-

```
const Greeting = require("../models/model.js");
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.message) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: "Note content can not be empty" });
  }
  const greeting = new Greeting({
    name: req.body.name || "Name Needed",
    message: req.body.message,
  });

  Greeting.pushData(greeting);
};
```

modules.js

```
const GreetingSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    message: String,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Greeting", GreetingSchema);
const Schema = mongoose.model("Greeting", GreetingSchema);


  pushData = (greeting) => {
     const data = new Schema({
       name: greeting.name,
       message: greeting.message
     });
    data
    .save()
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res
        .status(500)
        .send({
          message: err.message || "Error Occurred while creating Greeting",
        });
    });
  }

module.exports = {pushData};
```

and getting errors:
*
TypeError: Greeting is not a constructor
at exports.create (E:\Projects\Greeting-App_backend - Copy\controller\controller.js:9:20)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Projects\Greeting-App_backend - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (E:\Projects\Greeting-App_backend - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few errors in your code.

1. pushData method should be part of Schema if you want to keep it inside models and access through model Schema. No need to export pushData if you do it like below.

```js
GreetingSchema.methods.pushData = (greeting) => {
  // your code
}
module.exports =  mongoose.model("Greeting", GreetingSchema);
```

2. In controller it will be -

```js
greeting.pushData(greeting);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that your Greeting model is not a constructor. Check your model again to see if it's in the right format of how to create constructor in Javascript.

```
function Greeting(greeting) {
    this.name = greeting.name;
    this.message = greeting.message;
}
```